# how to get access_token from content response laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, token, access-token

I have this response content from api response:

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":31535919,"access_token":"eyJ0eXa99e760ef4e468d17198f9fa6be9d67c36240a9bf9bb74d76b18e18ca2661706e33d1bc80cdAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSU.......
```

How I can get the `access_token` value? So I can use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting JSON data in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511425/getting-json-data-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode` function to conver that into object and access it there.

```
$response = '{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":31535919,"access_token":"eyJ0eXa99e760ef4e468d17198f9fa6be9d67c36240a9bf9bb74d76b18e18ca2661706e33d1bc80cdAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSU.......';

$response = json_decode($response, true);
echo $response['access_token'];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Got this ErrorException: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Based on your code I have provided a solution. If thats not working try `json_decode(json_encode($response), true);`

Comment: Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
got this

Comment: Sorry. My Bad. Updated my comment.

Comment: $response=json_decode(json_encode($response1), true);
        dd($response['access_token']); Got this ErrorException: Undefined index: access_token

Comment: trying to dd the response give me empty like this    array:1 [
  "baseResponse" => array:3 [
    "headers" => []
    "original" => []
    "exception" => null
  ]
]